# How to tell if you're running through Pythonwin or console

Tags: python, user-interface, input, console-application

I'm using PythonWin. If in the IDE I click Run, then any `input()` commands will pop up as a windows message box. But in the console they are printed console commands.

I tried using `msvcrt.getch()` in PythonWin, and it returns the character `\xFF` every time.

I would like to have my program use `msvcrt.getch()` if it's in the console, and `input()` if it's in PythonWin. So, how can my program tell which one it's running in?

Comment: Does `os.isatty(...)` help?

Comment: What do I pass to it?

Comment: Try passing `sys.stdin.fileno()` and the same for `stdout`. If you are in a regular console it should return `True`. Otherwise it will return `False` or throw an exception.

Comment: Cool, that works! Is there an advantage or disadvantage of using `os.isatty` as opposed to `"pywin.framework.startup" in sys.modules`?

Comment: Looks like `os.isatty` has one advantage: in DreamPie `msvcrt.getch()` doesn't work, `os.isatty` is `False` and `"pywin.framework.startup" in sys.modules` is `False`.

Comment: If you only need it for PythonWin, then no. But the `isatty` method works for other shells as well (IDLE, IPython...)

Comment: Want to post it as an answer? I'll upvote it.

Comment: Weird, in IDLE `sys.stdin.fileno()` throws an error `UnsupportedOperation: fileno`

Comment: Look at `type(sys.stdin)`. In IDLE it returns `<class 'idlelib.rpc.RPCProxy'>` and not a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if you are in a regular shell (python.exe) or a custom one (IPython, PythonWin, DreamPie...) by using `os.isatty`:

```
import os
import sys
import io

try:
    if os.isatty(sys.stdin.fileno()):
        print "msvcrt.getch() will work."
    else:
        print "msvcrt.getch() will fail."
except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):
    print "msvcrt.getch() will fail."
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good, but it's usually good to have it catch an exception and not be a blank `except:`. So it could be `except Exception:` or `except io.UnsupportedOperation` or `except ValueError`.

Comment: Edited to reflect that. I hope it catches all relevant exceptions now.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out a solution by stepping into the source code of `input()` when running through PythonWin. I am posting here so that others who run across this issue will have a solution.

`"pywin.framework.startup" in sys.modules` is `True` when running in PythonWin, but `False` when running in the console.

So my code looks like this:

```
if "pywin.framework.startup" in sys.modules:
    move = raw_input(promptstr)
else:
    print(promptstr)
    move = msvcrt.getch()
```